# Nestjs / Typeorm transaction Save function is not working

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am new to nestjs and I am also self leaner.I need to add Data to two tables using transactions. I am using TypeORm for my ORM tool with Nestjs. I look the nestjs doc for the Typeform transaction and the document is not matching my scenario. So I create my own code, But it's networking. I really need your help.

This is my service code :

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Order)
    private readonly orderRepository: Repository<Order>,
    private readonly orderHasItemService: OrderHasItemService,
    private connection: Connection,
  ) {}
  async create(orderData: CreateOrderDto): Promise<string> {
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    const orderModel: {
      created_date: Date;
      status: string;
      customer: Customer;
    } = {
      status: orderData.status,
      created_date: orderData.created_date,
      customer: orderData.customer,
    };
    const oderDetailsModel: {
      item_id: string;
      qty: number;
      unit_price: number;
      order_id: string;
    } = {
      order_id: orderData.order_id,
      item_id: orderData.item_id,
      unit_price: orderData.unit_price,
      qty: orderData.qty,
    };
    const order = this.orderRepository.create(orderModel);
    if (order) {
      await queryRunner.connect();
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();
      try {
        const creatOrder = await queryRunner.manager.save(Order, orderModel);
        if (creatOrder) {
          return this.orderHasItemService.create(oderDetailsModel);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      } finally {
        await queryRunner.release();
      }
    }
   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In TypoORM(as in other ORMs) to create a row in your database, you need at first run `CREATE` and after it `SAVE` on the created model. Try to save your model:

```js
const order = this.orderRepository.create(orderModel);
                            // order instead of orderModel ||
                            //                             \/
const creatOrder = await queryRunner.manager.save(Order, order);
```